# How to check new posts since users last login Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

**Intro:** I have a 3 models `user`, `post`, `group`. User is able to make posts however each post has to belong to a group. Users have to choose from the existing groups for their posts. Users cannot add, delete, update group's.

Furthermore:

Users can become a member of groups and when they click on a certain group. They see all the posts in that group.

**What I want** When Users come on the home page they see posts that were added since the last time they logged in

[image]

**My Models**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**My Views**

```
class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Homepage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = Group.objects.all()
        context['post_list'] = Post.objects.order_by("-created_at")

        #What am I doing wrong in the below code
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated(): 
             new_posts = Post.objects.filter(created_at__gt(self.request.user.last_login))
             context['new_posts'] = new_posts.count()
        return context
```

In my templates I have

```
<div class="list-group">
        {% for group in object_list %}            
            {{group.name}} 
            {% if new_posts > 0 %}        
            {{new_posts}} new
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

> NameError: name 'created_at__gt' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because of you've missed a **Equal to symbol**,

```
new_posts = Post.objects.filter(created_at__gt = self.request.user.last_login)
                                              ^^^ here
```

Comment: awesome that did it

Comment: The filtering is correct, but in practice this shouldn't really work? When the user logs in, the last_login is set to now, and running the above filter should not result in any posts, as they are all made before before now? Wouldn't we need a previous_login to do this?